# How to find form submit input in Protractor

Tags: protractor

For fun/practice I write a test for Google advanced search and I am looking for a locator that will allow to find the form submit on https://www.google.com/advanced_search:

```
<input class="jfk-button jfk-button-action dUBGpe" 
 style="-webkit-user-select:none;user-select:none;line-height:100%;height:30px;min-width:120px" 
 value="Wyszukiwanie zaawansowane" type="submit">
```

As you can see this submit does not have id nor name defined so `by.id()` or `by.name()` cannot be used.

Answer (score 4):

[by.css](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.By.css) locates elements using a CSS selector. It allows you to simply use [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) for locating elements in the DOM.

```
element(by.css('input[type="submit"]'))
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the form submit the `by.xpath` locator can be used:

```
element(by.xpath("//input[@type='submit']"));
```

Answer (score 0):

What locator will suite You depends of the whole page, but here are few locators you can try:

```
element(by.xpath("//input[@class='jfk-button jfk-button-action dUBGpe']"));
element(by.css("jfk-button.jfk-button-action.dUBGpe"));
```